# OpenCL GEMM on Mali & adreno GPU's

Tags: opencl, matrix-multiplication, gpu

I tried using existing OpenCL BLAS libraries like clBLAS, CLBlast, ARM compute library for GEMM operation (matrix multiplication). But their performance seems to be sub optimal on these GPU's.

Are there any sample custom GEMM implementations available for Mobile GPU's like Mali & Adreno GPU that provide good performance?

Comment: In what way their performance is sub-optimal? what are you comparing it against?

Comment: In terms of GFLOPS, I saw many github issues where the authors of these libraries mentioned that the OpenCL drivers in these GPU's aren't promoting unrolling & other techniques used in the existing libraries. They also mentioned that hand crafted kernels were 40% faster than these libraries. I couldn't find any such hand crafted kernels though